# Generate new record from fixture

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, fixtures

I have a fixture called "group":

```
one:
   customer: one
   name: MyString
```

In one test I need a couple more so I would like to do something like:

```
  (1..3).each { |t| Group.create!(groups(:one), name: "Group #{t}")}
```

Is there a way to do something like that with fixtures? (The above of course doesn't work). I know that I could use factories but I want to keep using fixtures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your second example is a kind of *Factory*.

if you want to use (yaml) fixtures, you can simply produce them with a script similar to your second example, along the lines of:

```
y = {"two" => {"customer" => "two", "name" => "londiwe"}}.to_yaml   
fi = open("groups.yml", "w")
fi.write(y)
fi.close
```

**edit after comment**:
if you just want to take attributes from an existing record and create new records based on that one record, use `clone`:
1. first find the record you want to clone:

```
orig = Group.find_by_customer("one")
```

2. create the clone, change its attributes and save it

```
(1..3).each do 
     tmp_clone = orig.clone 
     tmp_clone.name = "two"
     tmp_clone.save
end
```

Comment: I don't think I quite get your idea? This will just generate a new fixture but what I want is just the attributes from the fixture and then change the name attribute. Something like g=Group.create!(groups(:one).attributes); g.update_attribute(:name, 'Group 2');

Comment: I've changed the answer following your comment. I would advice using either fixtures or factories in order to keep your tests clean and readable however.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your fixtures just like active record objects.

```
# get attr from fixture & delete id
attr_from_fixture = groups(:one).attributes
attr_from_fixture.delete('id')

# create new
(1..3).each do |t| 
   attr_from_fixture[:name] = "Group #{t}"
   Group.create!(attr_from_fixture)
end
```

**UPDATE: even easier**

Just remembered the [clone](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/clone) method, even easier

```
(1..3).each do |t| 
   new_group = groups(:one).clone
   new_group.name = "Group #{t}"
   new_group.save
end
```

Answer (score 1):

#dup returns a new object.  Clones attrs without id.

```
(1..3).each do |t| 
   new_group = groups(:one).dup
   new_group.name = "Group #{t}"
   new_group.save
end
```